# Stripe Connect in Ionic Cordova - Can't redirect back to application

Tags: cordova, redirect, ionic-framework, stripe-connect

**Framework:** Ionic Cordova

**API:** Stripe Connect (allows users to send payments to each other).

The registration process for *getting* payments is through Stripe Connects own external window. When registering for Stripe Connect it uses a Redirect URI, (which is set in the settings of my Stripe account) to go back to the screen you came from with an authentication code. This works in browser (because Redirect URI is set to localhost or an IP), but the actual running application on a phone doesn't, because the application doesn't have a URL. So it shows a "site is not accessible/doesn't exist" browser error message.

I currently use open the Stripe Connect registration screen by using:

```
  var link = "https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=MYCLIENTID&scope=read_write";

    window.open(link, '_blank', 'location=no');
```

- I've asked Stripe support for help, but they have no solution for this.
- I've tried using the [Custom URL Scheme](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme) for giving the application a URL - but Stripe only allow "Http://" URL's, and not CoolAppName//:, as the Custom URL Scheme gives.
- Please do not get confused by this one: If I run "ionic run -l" in cmd, and then use the given URL as Redirect URI, it actually redirects back with the authentication code on phone as well. BUT, erases every information stored in application, so it "forgets" what user is logged in. Of course this solution will only work locally as well.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can use any url you want, what you have to do is to listen for the `loadstart` event and check if it's loading that url to know if the redirection was ok

First install inAppBrowser plugin if you haven't done it already
`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`

and use `window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open` instead of `window.open` (the API changed long time ago)

Your code should be something like this:

```
var link = "https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=MYCLIENTID&scope=read_write";

var browserRef = window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open(link, '_blank', 'location=no');

browserRef.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
    if((event.url).indexOf(yourRedirectUri) === 0) {
        //Loaded the redirect url
    }
});
```

Where `yourRedirectUri` is the url you used on stripe

Comment: This answer might have been true back when OP asked but as of 2021, you cannot frame Stripe Connect or any Stripe services at all for that matter. The only way to do this in a Cordova app is to redirect to a page on your server that will redirect to your app and from that page you collect the details of the redirect.